# Let L = $\frac{f^{2n-2}(0)}{\left(2n-2\right)!}$ and Let M = $\sum_{n=1}^{102}(-1)^{n-1}(L)$. Evaluate M.

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, algebra-precalculus, determinant

Let **A = $\left[a_{ij}\right]_{(2n-1)(2n-1)}$** (n ∈ **N**) denote a **square matrix** of order [ **2n - 1** ] and
\begin{equation}
[a_{ij}] = 
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        \frac{1}{2}(2n^2+i+j+2-4n),  i = j\\
        \frac{1}{2}(2n^2+i-j+2+4n),i≠j
    \end{array}
\right\}
\end{equation}

Let **f(x)** **=** **| xI - A |**. Let **L = $\frac{f^{2n-2}(0)}{\left(2n-2\right)!}$** and Let **M** = $\sum_{n=1}^{102}(-1)^{n-1}(L)$.

Here, **$f^k(o)$** represents the **$k^{th}$ derivative** of **y = f(x)** at **x = 0**,

[**I** represents an Identity matrix and |D| represents the **determinant** value of any matrix 'D']

Evaluate **M**.

This question is from highschool test and during the test, I started with taking the case n = 2 and create the matrix which in my case was $[a_{ij}]_{(3 \,x \, 3)}$,

$$A = 
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    2 & 0.5 & 0 \\
    1.5 & 3 & 0.5 \\
   2 & 1.5 & 4 
  \end{array}\right]
$$

which makes 'I' naturally a $3\,x\,3$ matrix,

$$f(x) = 
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    x-2 & -0.5 & 0 \\
    -1.5 & x-3 & 0.5 \\
   -2 & -1.5 & x-4 
  \end{array}\right]
$$
Then, on taking n = 2 in L, we get L = $\frac{f^2(0)}{2!}$,
before which we need f'(x) so to get that obviously we expand the matrix f(x) giving us;

| f(x) | = $x^3-9x^2-26x-23 $ after which, L = -9 and similarly M.

NOTE-I am interested to learn a method which doesn't involve characteristic equation. The question however has two elegant answers below using characteristic equation.

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth reading more about the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) (its expressions and interesting math around it) to get a sense of direction since that is what your f(x) is coincidentally describing.

As for giving you a starting point, this may be helpful:
using Jacobi's formula, you can evaluate
$$
\begin{align}
f^1(x)&=det|xI-A|\cdot tr\left((xI-A)^{-1} \frac{d (xI-A)}{dx}\right) \\
&= f(x)\cdot tr\left((xI-A)^{-1} I\right) \\
&= f(x)\cdot tr\left(\frac{1}{det|xI-A|}adj(xI-A) \right) \\
&= f(x)\cdot tr\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}adj(xI-A) \right) \\
&= tr\left(adj(xI-A) \right) \\
\end{align}
$$
and you could continue from there.

PS: What high school test is this a part of (just curious)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $A,f,L$ should be indexed by $n.$

$$\begin{align}-L_n&=\operatorname{tr}(A_n)\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{2n-1}(n^2+j+1-2n)\\&=(2n-1)(n-1)^2+\sum_{j=1}^{2n-1}j\\&=(2n-1)(n-1)^2+n(2n-1)\\&=(2n-1)(n^2-n+1)\\&=2n^3-3n^2+3n-1\\&=n^3+(n-1)^3.
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}M&=\sum_{n=1}^{102}(-1)^n(n^3+(n-1)^3)\\&=102^3,
\end{align}$$
by [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).